# Save image name in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to read current image file name or image name, e.g 0.png or 1.png, but failing. I am trying as follows and more. In the below code, `images` is a list that already contains

```
images.Add(Image.FromFile(fileinfo.FullName));
```

Any suggestion or idea will be helpful. Is it possible or not to store file name at the current position of my program?

```
foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls) // run loop untill every control inside tablelayoutpanel1.Controls is check or read
    {
        Button btns = control as Button;   // btn sotre the current button in table.contr 
        if (btns != null)                  // check btn got a button from the panel then
        {
            int randomNumber = random.Next(images.Count);   // pic the random image from list by its index which are already in images list and also count how many are they
            //MessageBox.Show(images.Count.ToString());     // if 6 images then 6 will be the max index value for 
            btns.BackgroundImage = images[randomNumber];    // change btn image to current random image
            copyImages.Add(images[randomNumber]);           // fileName.Add(** here some query for storing current image file name required**);   
            btns.BackgroundImage = null;
            images.RemoveAt(randomNumber);  // remove the current image index from list 
            //btns.Hide();
        }
    }
```

`fileName` is a list which I created. I just want to store file name on its 0 index up or can I do something like that set the image: store the name of the image in the Tag property of the Button? If yes, how?

Comment: So aside from the bug spotted by @SteveWellens, you want to set the image on the button and store the filename on the button tag?

Comment: any way i dont have any compile issues i have already set the image on button randomly which is showing on click as well i just want to know thier name so that i can compare weather both images are same e.g i have 1.png and 1 more 1.png if both button background image name is 1 i want to do something like showing message box that both are same images hope you get my point.

Comment: It's not a compile issue, it's button background image is horribly blank issue.

Comment: its not a bug i m purposly nullifying them cz i dont want them to be seen untill they are clicked and i m also copying them in a different list, why every one saying that its a bug :(. Thanks for the help though :). and i cant post my whole project here so i cant explain more

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an image to the button and then removing it:

```
btns.BackgroundImage = images[randomNumber]; 
...
btns.BackgroundImage = null;
```

That can't be right.

Comment: i am copying the image by copyImages.Add(images[randomNumber]); in a different list randomly for further use i want to know i how can i keep track of thier names suppose if store thier name in a different array or list but once they randomize i lost track on them more the real question i ask is how can i get the file name of the image e.g 123.png is the file name how can i get that at the particular piece of code if its possible

Comment: As Tony Hopkinson has pointed out, it is up to you to manage the names...if you really need to.

Comment: o yes thanks i can give them name by myself :) Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Well aside from the bug spotted by Steve Wellens
A few ways to do that.
Simplest is

Make Images a `List<String>` of filenames.
Then call From File in your loop
e.g

```
btns.Tag = images[randomnumber];
btns.BackgroundImage = ImageFromFile(images[randomNumber]);
```

If you have some deep seated need to load all the images up before you use them.
Then other options would be a struct or a class (FileName and Image) and have a list of them.

Or if the filenames are unique make images a `Dictionary<string,Image>`, where string is the filename and use it's `Keys.Count` and `Keys.ElementAt` methods to make your loop work.

Comment: its not a bug i m purposly nullifying them cz i dont want them to be seen untill they are clicked and i m also copying them in a different list, why every one saying that its a bug :(. Thanks for the help though :).

Comment: You confused us when you assigned and then unassigned. What else would we think? A lot of code comprehension is intent, setting BackgroundImage suggested an intent of having a background image...

Comment: Based on later comments. you just need images to be a list of strings then, assign to the tag property of the button, then use that to load the image in the click event handler. Job done

Comment: :) i wish i can share my project with you. You can send me hi to my gmail which is displayed on my profile i ll send you the proj.